# Tangent point in Polar Coordinates

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I don't know which command to determine the tangent lines that are parallel to the line $x=0$ (i.e. the y-axis) in ***Polar Coordinates***. Can you help me please to give me some suggestions?

I attach some code which I have written:

```
theta = 45;
the = theta*Pi/180;
alp = 2;
gc = Sqrt[1 + alp*Sin[x - the]*Sin[x - the]];
yy = 1/gc;
PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
 Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]
```

Comment: Why not switch to parametric equations? `#2/#1 & @@ D[yy {Cos[x], Sin[x]}, x]`?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. YOU mean ff = #1/#2 & @@ D[yy {Cos[x], Sin[x]}, x]; mm = Solve[ff == 0, x]; here not #2/#1, Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yy = 1 / gc;
f[x_] := Evaluate[yy {Cos[x], Sin[x]}]
tangent[x_] := Evaluate[Simplify@FrenetSerretSystem[f[x], x][[2, 1]]]

pts1 = N[x /. Solve[{Divide @@ tangent[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x, Reals]]
```

> {0.197395, 3.33898}

```
pts2 = N[x /. Solve[{Divide[#2, #1] & @@ tangent[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x, Reals]]
```

> {4.51499, 1.3734007}

```
epilog = {Text[Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "°", Black],
       {.1, .05} + (f@#)] & /@ Join[pts1, pts2], 
    Thick, Purple, PointSize[Large] , Point[f /@ pts1], 
    Magenta, Point[f /@ pts2], Green, Point[f[#]], 
    Cyan, Line /@ ({{# - 1/3, #2}, {# + 1/3, #2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts2)), 
    Orange, Line /@ ({{#, #2 - 1/3}, {#, #2 + 1/3}} & @@@ (f /@ pts1)), 
    Red, Line[{f[#] - .5 tangent[#], f[#] + .5 tangent[#]}]} &;

Manipulate[PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> epilog[-t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100}]
```

[image]

Using OP's code with the option `Epilog`:

```
PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
 Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Purple, PointSize[Large] , Point[f /@ pts1], 
   Magenta, Point[f /@ pts2], 
   Cyan, Line /@ ({{# - 1/2, #2}, {# + 1/2, #2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts2)), 
   Orange, Line /@ ({{#, #2 - 1/2}, {#, #2 + 1/2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts1))}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Starting with `theta = 65;` and going through the same steps:

```
PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
 Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "°", Black],
       {.1, .05} + (f@#)] & /@ Join[pts1, pts2] , 
   Thick, Purple, PointSize[Large], Point[f /@ pts1], 
   Magenta, Point[f /@ pts2], 
   Cyan, Line /@ ({{# - 1/2, #2}, {# + 1/2, #2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts2)), 
   Orange, Line /@ ({{#, #2 - 1/2}, {#, #2 + 1/2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts1))}]
```

[image]

Comment: search the node: the tangent of node is parallel to the line x=0 ... not tangent in every node...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM,  please see the update.

Comment: nice to see! thanks a lot!

Comment: is it possible that in the near of each node I can add the value of [Degrees], example: P1 = 10,33 Degree? P.S. I can do it in PPTX ...

Comment: you mean Text[Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "°", Black] in labels ?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, yes.

Comment: your code contains bug, that means if theta = 65, it won't work.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM,  what do you get? Note that the function `tangent` is based on `yy` which, in turn takes `theta =45 Degree` as given. When you change `theta` to a different value you need to re-evaluate `yy` , `tangent`, `pts1` and `pts2` to get the correct picture.

Comment: if theta=65, pts1 can not be solved...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, I get `pts1 ={3.65544, 0.51385}` and `pts2={4.43026, 1.28867}` for `theta = 65`. (Please note that I use `yy = 1 /gc` , not `yy = 1. / gc`)

Comment: why we can not use 1.?

Comment: if I use second example, I can not add Degree symbol "Text[Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "°", Black],
       {.1, .05} + (f@#)] & /@ Join[pts1, pts2], 
    Thick, Purple, PointSize[Large] , Point[f /@ pts1], 
    Magenta, Point[f /@ pts2], Green, Point[f[#]],"

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, I posted the picture I get for `theta = 65` including the labels. Re why not `1.`, `Solve` works better with exact numbers( i.e., `1/2` rather than `.5` ).

Comment: okay,  thanks a lot for your support!